# count number of words in a string (not only latin languages)

Tags: php, internationalization

If I am not wrong Chinese language (and other languages) doesn't use space `' '` as word delimiter.

So which could be a good algorithm that works internationally?

Comment: That depends on the word delimiter for that language. Out of curiosity, how does a chinese word end?

Comment: And here is the answer: http://www.anycount.com/WordCountBlog/tag/word-count-in-chinese/

Comment: this already looks like a massive headache can't wait to see the answer for this one.

Comment: @Indranil it doesn't. "words" are sets of n characters which are not separated visually from succeeding or preceding words except on either side of a punctuation mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technique I've seen used a lot is to simply count the number of characters used and divide this by the average characters per word in Chinese. A number that is often used for this is 1.5

If your Chinese text has 1500 characters, it's approximately 1000 words long.

I am not aware of a more accurate way of counting words, except for interpreting the text itself. This would mean actually understanding the context of the words used, since a Chinese character can sometimes be used as a word by itself, but also as a component in a composite word.

Comment: It seems to be the right ratio: http://www.proz.com/forum/linguistics/58362-word_count_for_chinese.html. "1.35:1~1.8:1. Usually, we take 1.5:1"